# "A user with this nickname already exists" exception whenever I try to register new user using Sitefinity

Tags: c#, .net, exception, content-management-system, sitefinity

I am trying to register a new user in Sitefinity. I have many custom fields also in the basic profile of Sitefinity. But I am getting

> A user with this nickname already exists

exception. When we check in Sitefinity backend users list there is no such user. I tried multiple times with different names but every time it is showing the same error.

Also on analysis, I found that this exception is happening when I try to save some value to the custom fields in Sitefinity basic profile. But that custom fields are not at all depending on the Nickname

> Telerik.Sitefinity.ModelValidationException: A user with this nickname already exists.
>
> at DynamicModule.ns.Wrapped_OpenAccessProfileProvider_53e4abda40a1409abf26fc8d136e21d7.CommitTransaction() at ...

This is the log I get.

Following is the code I use. I am not sure why this exception is coming when I try to save a field which is not depending on the nickname.

```
UserManager userManager = UserManager.GetManager();
userManager.Provider.SuppressSecurityChecks = true;
UserProfileManager profileManager = UserProfileManager.GetManager();
RoleManager roleManager = RoleManager.GetManager();
User user = userManager.CreateUser(userProfile.Email, userProfile.Password, userProfile.Email, "", "", true, null, out status);
if (status == MembershipCreateStatus.Success)
{
   SitefinityProfile sfProfile = profileManager.CreateProfile(user, 
   Guid.NewGuid(), typeof(SitefinityProfile)) as SitefinityProfile;

   sfProfile.FirstName = userProfile.FirstName;
   sfProfile.LastName = userProfile.LastName;

   if (sfProfile.DoesFieldExist("PocketGuidePushNotifications"))
   {
      sfProfile.SetValue("PocketGuidePushNotifications", true);
      profileManager.SaveChanges(); // Exception when executing this line
   }
   //There are other custom fields getting updated too in the same way.
   userManager.SaveChanges();
   profileManager.RecompileItemUrls(sfProfile);
   profileManager.SaveChanges();
   roleManager.Provider.SuppressSecurityChecks = true;
   var role = roleManager.GetRole("RoleName");
   roleManager.AddUserToRole(user, role);
   roleManager.SaveChanges();
   roleManager.Provider.SuppressSecurityChecks = false;
   userManager.Provider.SuppressSecurityChecks = false;
}
```

"PocketGuidePushNotifications" this is the name of custom Sitefinity user field I created in Basic profile.
Can anyone please help me with this issue?

Comment: You should edit your question and add how you check if the user exists and how you assign the `user`  properties. This lacks a [mcve]

Comment: Can you also include the code that inits the user variable? Also, is the user that the thread is running under an Admin user?

Comment: @VeselinVasilev I have edited the code in the question to add user creating lines. This is written as a Web API and it is running as admin. Hope I answered your questions.

Answer (score 0):

I assigned nickname separately in the code as

```
sfProfile.FirstName = userProfile.FirstName;
sfProfile.LastName = userProfile.LastName;
sfProfile.Nickname = userProfile.FirstName + " " + userProfile.LastName;
```

I am still not sure why Sitefinity was not taking its default value. In another coding environment, it was taking the default value as Firstname + Lastname without assigning separately in code. If anyone knows the reason please do share.

Answer (score 0):

While saving the changes to SitefinityProfile if

> the Nickname is Null or Empty, Sitefinity automatically generates the
>   nickname.
>    Please refer below snippet

```
        private string GenerateNickName()
        {
            this.NickNameAutoGenerated = true;
            string empty = string.Empty;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.FirstName) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.LastName))
            {
                empty = string.Concat(this.FirstName, " ", this.LastName);
            }
            else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.FirstName))
            {
                empty = this.FirstName;
            }
            else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.LastName))
            {
                empty = this.LastName;
            }
            else if (this.User.Email.Contains("@"))
            {
                string email = this.User.Email;
                char[] chrArray = new char[] { '@' };
                empty = email.Split(chrArray).FirstOrDefault<string>();
            }
            if (empty.Length > 60)
            {
                empty = empty.Substring(0, 60);
            }
            return empty;
        }
```

Hope this might help.